# Einstein Bot - is it possible to change the message from “Bot is responding” to “Different text”?

Tags: einstein, chat, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

My requirement is to make updates to a message during the time when the bot is typing.

FYI - I am using Einstein Enhanced Bot.

[image]

If I uncheck the Typing Indicator checkbox, it only eliminates the message indicating that the bot is typing.

[image]